# R: how to get the covariance matrix of the error after model fitting

Tags: r

After fitting the linear model using `lm`, how to see the covariance matrix of the error after fitting? Say we have the model `Y=Xb+e`, where we assume `e ~ N(0,V)`. How could we get an estimate of the matrix `V`?

Thanks!

Comment: The residuals are not *"the residuals of the coefficients"* but the differences between the observed and predicted value (`summary.lm` gives you Tukey's five number summary of these values). Did you take a look at `?summary.lm` and `?lm`? This seems to be more of a general stats question in which case SO is not the right forum. Perhaps consider reposting on Cross Validated; better yet, these are some pretty basic questions that any R tutorial on linear models and/or R-focussed stats textbook would address.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the *"covariance matrix of the error after fitting"*; `vcov(fit)` gives you the variance-covariance matrix of the model parameters. Is that what you're after?

Comment: @MauritsEvers Thanks, and I already tried this, but the dimension looks weird...Say my `y` is of length 5, but `vcov` gives a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: Nothing weird about it; as I said, `vcov` gives you the variance-covariance matrix **of the parameters**. 3 model parameters will give you a `3x3` matrix.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Sorry, I did not say it clear. I was trying to get the covariance matrix of the error, or you can say the covariance matrix of the observations, since these two matrix are the same.

Comment: I have never heard of a *"covariance matrix of the error"*; in a univariate linear model `e ~ N(0, sigma^2)`, where `sigma` is the standard deviation of the underlying normal distribution.

Comment: @MauritsEvers So we should assume we know `sigma` but we can not compute it right? But how to pick `sigma`?

Comment: You can get the estimated standard deviation of the errors with `sigma(your_lm_fit)`, see `?sigma` for details.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Hi, I just tried, it returns `Inf`. I guess there might be something wrong with my data matrix.